# How to find where the error occurs while debugging angularJS which is used with c#

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am using angularJS with C# and i am getting error on POST request but i cannot know what caused the error while debugging

It is entering in error section while debugging in chrome browser but i am not clear why is that happening.

```
var req = {
    method:'POST',
    url:'ActionList.aspx/AddAction',
    data:
    {
        strAction: $scope.mdlAction, intCategory: $scope.mdlCategory, intAsssignedTo: $scope.mdlAssignedTo,
        strDueDate:$scope.dtDueDate
    }
}
$http(req).success(function(data){
    result = angular.fromJson(data.d);
    if (result.status == "success") {
        alert('its working');
    }
}).error(function (data) {
    alert('its an error');
    console.log('error: Could not add the student');
});
```

```c
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static string AddAction(String strAction,int intCategory,int 
 intAssignedTo,String strDueDate)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; 
charset=utf-8";
        ActionList AL = new ActionList();
        dynamic json = new JObject();
        obj.AddAction(strAction, intCategory, intAssignedTo, strDueDate);
        json.status = "success";
        return json.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        dynamic d = new JObject();
        d.status = "error";
        return d.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look into `data` of `.error( function(data) { ... ` ? What does it say? And maybe log or output the exception message. Or even better: Set a breakpoint in the catch clause and examine the exception object (Message, Stacktrace).

Comment: some reference error they are saying

Comment: then please add the message and stacktrace. It might be as simple as a missing "using" statement.

Comment: N.B. if it's a server-side error (i.e. you get a 500 Internal Server Error response) then you need to debug the C# code instead, and/or look in the server logs

Comment: stack: "ReferenceError: data is not defined↵    at eval (eval at serviceObj.AddAction (http://localhost:14221/JzeroInternalSystem/ActionList.aspx:25:20), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at Object.serviceObj.AddAction (http://localhost:14221/JzeroInternalSystem/ActionList.aspx:157:20)↵    at b.$scope.ctrAddAction (http://localhost:14221/JzeroInternalSystem/ActionList.aspx:171:25)↵    at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:231:409), <anonymous>:4:227)↵    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:126:19)↵

Comment: at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:274:394)↵    at b.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:107)↵    at b.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:340)↵    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:274:446)↵    at Sf (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:37:33)"

Comment: @ADyson i cannot debug c# code as i have used ng-click over the markup page and rest of the things are done with this POST request

Comment: @BKM none of that is relevant to debugging the C#. If you are running the C# with Visual Studio then you can use the Visual Studio debugger. it can run at the same time. Or you can make sure your application logs exceptions and then check the logs.

Comment: okay yes nice idea let me log them thanks

Comment: To be honest: That Server code seems to be rubbish. `ActionList AL = new ActionList();` is not used at all, `obj.AddAction(...` "obj" is not declared nor instantiated anywhere ... That code shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @BKM I notice that in the C# you are using `try...catch` without actually saving the generated exception. This is an anti-pattern. You are throwing away useful information. Catching exceptions is ok but you have to make sure you log the error. Otherwise if something is going wrong in the C# code you have no way of understanding what the problem is, and therefore no way of fixing it.

Comment: ^-- Which you already have a textbook example of here ;)

Comment: @BKM as for the JS error, it reports `ReferenceError: data is not defined`...which line of your code throws that error exactly? We can't see your line numbers, don't forget.

Comment: @fildor i have used  `ActionList AL = new ActionList();` to use the value of session variable which i cant in static method directly  as of now i have removed that parameter to check it works without it 
and for obj i have declared that gloabaly

Comment: i am sorry if i ate your time @fildor and adyson but thanks for putting efforts and yes i will log the exception from now good learning

Comment: You're welcome. Just keep in mind that we can only see what you provide in the question. There are several guidelines on how to write "[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Maybe give them a read.